# Error: [Header] is not a <Route> component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I continue to run into the above mentioned error despite my efforts to fix them. The terminal claims the application compiles without issue but nothing shows up on the browser. I found the error my looking at the console. Here is the index.js file for the Header component that the error is referring to:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Navigate, Router } from "react-router-dom";
import Navigation from "../../components/Navigation";
import About from "../../components/About";
import Portfolio from "../../components/Portfolio";
import Contact from '../../components/Contact';
import Resume from '../../components/Resume';

class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <header>
          <Navigation />
        </header>

        <div className="content">
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Navigate to="/about" replace={true}/>} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio} />
          <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
          <Route path="/resume" component={Resume}/>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Here is the App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Header />
        <Footer />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I can provide further code if it is needed.

Comment: Routes should probably have Route as children. Remove the Routes from App and place it in Header and check if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` version 6 `Routes` components can have only `Route` or `React.Fragment` as a child component, and `Route` components can have only `Routes` or another `Route` component as parent. `Header` is not a `Route` component and fails the invariant.

Move the `Router` into app and render the `Header` and `Footer` components into it instead, then wrap the `Route` components in `Routes`.

App

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Header

Fix the `Route` components, they no longer use `component` or `render` to render the routed components, instead they now use an `element` prop to render `ReactElement`s, i.e. JSX.

```
class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <header>
          <Navigation />
        </header>

        <div className="content">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/about" replace />} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="/portfolio" element={<Portfolio />} />
            <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />}/>
            <Route path="/resume" element={<Resume />}/>
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Though it may make more sense to move the routes into the app as content between the header and footer.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <div className="content">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/about" replace />} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="/portfolio" element={<Portfolio />} />
            <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />}/>
            <Route path="/resume" element={<Resume />}/>
          </Routes>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Imports for App
```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Router } from 'express';
```
Header
```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Navigate, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Navigation from "../../components/Navigation";
import About from "../../components/About";
import Portfolio from "../../components/Portfolio";
import Contact from '../../components/Contact';
import Resume from '../../components/Resume';
```

Comment: Are those the correct imports?

Comment: @KendraStaver The `import { Router } from 'express';` seems highly suspect to me. It should be probably one of the high-level routers from `react-router-dom`, example `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Navigate, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';`.

Comment: Okay! I will try that. I no longer get the original error anymore! however I do have 73 vulnerabilities in my `node_modules` files...